# vue-chartjs remove top rectangle (datasets label)

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

[render chart view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJvqu.png)

[how the chart looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8BFt.png)

So I feel like I've tried everything under the sun to remove that red rectangle above the chart. Anyone know how to remove it? Most of the examples with setting up options and legend like below might work with chartjs but not vue-chartjs if I'm not mistaken.

```
    options: {
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You litterly posted the answer yourself, the second object in the renderChart function is the options object so if you put it like this it will work:

`{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: true, legend: { display: false } }`

Next time please dont post a screenshot of your code but include it as text in your post since it is a lot easyer to read and use for people

Comment: Thank you that worked, I didn't try to plug it down there. This was my first question next one will look better thanks for the tip!